# How do I update my billing information?

Tags: online-accounts

I need to update my billing information to add a new credit card, but I cannot seem to find the place to do this on the website. Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: So we are to guess what you are on about? :) An URL would help :)

Comment: Billing information for what?

Answer (score 0):

*I'm assuming you are talking about your Ubuntu One account*

As per the [Ubuntu One FAQ](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/how-do-i-update-the-credit-card-on-my-account/):

> Currently you need to cancel your subscription and sign up again. You
>   can cancel your subscription by going to:
>
> 1. Go to https://one.ubuntu.com/account
> 2. Click on the "See details" button next to your paid subscription
> 3. Click on the "Cancel this subscription" button
>
> Then sign up for the subscription again at https://one.ubuntu.com/services
>
> We're working on fixing this so you can update your credit card on
>   file. Apologies for the inconvenience.